# How do I use random color script to fill up the circular patterns that I have created using Phantasm version?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, illustrator-scripting, illustrator-effects, symbols

[image]

I have already expanded the appearance, broken the symbol link of the halftone patterns and ungrouped it. I want to fill up with several colors using random color fill script but it's not working.

Comment: Are all your paths individual paths?

Comment: Are you using the script from [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/113896/63979)?

Comment: Yes, it is and yeah I'm using that script.

Comment: Are you able to upload your ai file? May have a better idea there.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14v6TlWYX4sxLHLn-p3HG2en-dhbIRu9o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Another way to do this would be a random selection script. Shouldn't be necessary here but just thought I'd put that out there. It would allow doing more things than just changing color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your paths are all in a clipping mask.

Go to the *Layers Panel* (<kbd>F7</kbd>) and you'll see that;

1. Your paths are in a clipping mask.
2. You have extra paths.

[image: layer panel]

Delete the extra paths, then select the main group and **Right Click → Release Clipping Mask** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>)

You now have to delete the extra "clipping path" (it will be a rectangle shape) above all your other shapes.

[image: clipping path]

Now select all and apply your random colors.

[image: Random Colors Applied]