# How do I create alternating patterns in illustrator using halftone effect and phantasm version

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, halftone

[image: Full image of the pattern I have created using Phantasm]

[Closed up Halftone Pattern I have created using Phantasm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84FSY.png)

[image: I want to make it like this]

As you can see, the patterns I have created are consistent and I was wondering if it's possible to make it non-consistent? (But the shape should still be going towards the centre)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand the paths first, see [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/121165/63979).

I would use multiple different randomize scripts to handle this.

---

#### [RandomResize](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/randomresizeopacity/22-1-0-152)

Will randomly resize all your paths (in a specific range), gives variation in size.

#### [RandomMove](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/111271/63979)

By @joojaa, you can use the GUI version to shift all the paths slightly (a few pts range)

#### [RandomRotate](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/free_script_random_rotate_linear_gradient/22-1-0-352)

You can rotate them all slightly to add some difference in angle.

---

This is my result after running the above scripts a few different times with different ranges etc.

[image: Result]